# Can we use Eclipse or Android Studio templates in IDEA?

Tags: android, templates, intellij-idea, intellij-13

Since IDEA is not so developer-friendly in terms of providing Android templates like Eclipse or Android Studio do, can we take those templates and use them in IDEA?

If yes, how can we do that, beside importing from its source folders? Maybe to get it in the right-click menu (like Android Studio, see below)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't take the templates out and use them in a context that's not designed for them; the templates require supporting code to instantiate them properly and insert the right parameters that you supply through the wizard. Android Studio and Eclipse have that code because they've been designed around those templates.